# Left outer join with left() function

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

I'm running the below query daily (overnight) and it's taking considerable time to run (1-1.5 hours). I'm certain the "Acc.DateKey >= LEFT (LocationKey, 8)" is the reason and if this part of the join is removed the query executes in around 5 minutes. I just cannot think of a more efficient way.

Acc.DateKey is a bigint typically 20180101 etc., with the location key being a bigint typically 201801011234 etc.

So far I've considered including a new column in the LO table "AccLocationKey" which will be inserted with the LEFT (LocationKey, 8) function when loaded.

I've decided to pose the question here first - could this be improved upon without changing the LO table?

```
SELECT
ISNULL(MAX(L.LocationKey),(SELECT MIN(LocationKey) FROM LO WHERE Location = Acc.Location)) AS LocationKey
FROM
Acc
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        LocationKey
        ,Location
    FROM
        LO
)AS L
ON Acc.Location = L.Location AND Acc.DateKey >= LEFT(LocationKey,8)
```

Comment: Could you please provide some dummy data and context around table sizes etc?

Comment: In general you of course want to avoid both inequalities and functions in join conditions. Could you post the table DDLs? Have you looked at the explain plan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's rewrite the query without the subquery in the `SELECT`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(L.LocationKey), MIN(L.MIN_LocationKey)) AS LocationKey
FROM Acc LEFT OUTER JOIN
     (SELECT MIN(l.LocationKey) OVER (PARTITION BY l.Location) as min_location,
             l.*
      FROM LO l
     ) L
     ON Acc.Location = L.Location AND Acc.DateKey >= LEFT(l.LocationKey, 8);
```

Probably your best chance at performance is to add a computed column and appropriate index.  So:

```
alter table lo add locationkey_datekey as (try_convert(bigint, LEFT(l.LocationKey, 8))) persisted;
```

Then, the appropriate index:

```
create index idx_lo_location_datekey on lo(location, locationkey_datekey);
```

Then use this in the query:

```
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(L.LocationKey), MIN(L.MIN_LocationKey)) AS LocationKey
FROM Acc LEFT OUTER JOIN
     (SELECT MIN(l.LocationKey) OVER (PARTITION BY l.Location) as min_location,
             l.*
      FROM LO l
     ) L
     ON Acc.Location = L.Location AND Acc.DateKey >= l.LocationKey_datekey;
```

Happily, this index will also work for the window function.